# DSpace 6.3. Внутренняя системная ошибка при отправке ресурса. Плавающий баг

Tags: java, jsp

Имеется репозитарий на базе DSpace 6.3 и Ubuntu 16.04. Ранее проблем не было, но после переноса на новый сервер появились ошибки при отправке нового ресурса. А именно:

**1.** "Внутренняя системная ошибка" после нажатия кнопки "Далее" на странице выбора файла.
Страница выбора файлов соответствует файлу choose-file.jsp из dspace/webapps/jspui/submit - здесь проблем нет.
После нажатия "Далее", выполняться начинает upload-file-list.jsp - здесь возникает ошибка.
Если точнее, то ошибка возникает в нижеуказанном месте кода, - если список  bitstreams оказывается (по непонятным причинам) пустым.

```
List<Bitstream> bitstreams = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getItemService().getNonInternalBitstreams(context, subInfo.getSubmissionItem().getItem());
List<Bundle> bundles = null;

if (bitstreams.get(0) != null) {
    bundles = bitstreams.get(0).getBundles();
}
```

В /var/log/tomcat8/localhost.[date].log выдается следующее:

```
20-Nov-2019 13:58:30.373 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.apache.jsp.submit.upload_002dfile_002dlist_jsp._jspService(upload_002dfile_002dlist_jsp.java:414)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:401)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.util.JSPManager.showJSP(JSPManager.java:64)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.submit.JSPStepManager.showJSP(JSPStepManager.java:370)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.submit.step.JSPUploadStep.showUploadFileList(JSPUploadStep.java:580)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.submit.step.JSPUploadStep.showUploadPage(JSPUploadStep.java:498)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.submit.step.JSPUploadStep.doPostProcessing(JSPUploadStep.java:452)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.submit.JSPStepManager.doStepEnd(JSPStepManager.java:407)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.submit.JSPStepManager.processStep(JSPStepManager.java:250)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.SubmissionController.doStep(SubmissionController.java:505)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.SubmissionController.doDSPost(SubmissionController.java:443)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.processRequest(DSpaceServlet.java:122)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.doPost(DSpaceServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.filter.RegisteredOnlyFilter.doFilter(RegisteredOnlyFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**2.** "Внутренняя системная ошибка" после принятия лицензионного соглашения (страница соответствует файлу show-license.jsp). Проблема обусловлена наличием некорректных символов в заголовке HTTP-запроса, о чем свидетельствует вывод в /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.[date].log

```
20-Nov-2019 16:18:33.882 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-30] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Обе ошибки плавающие: могут возникать, могут не возникать. Если нажимать кнопку "Назад", и пробовать повторять запрос, иногда пропускает далее. Иногда помогает переход в "Мой архив ресурсов", где может отображаться ранее загруженный файл. Если удалить ресурс, и повторить всё заново, ошибки могут не возникнуть. Но обычно возникают.
Закономерностей никаких не выявлено.

Ошибки не связаны с загруженностью сервера: памяти и дискового пространства более чем достаточно. Ошибка может возникать, даже если пробовать добавлять ресурс среди ночи.

Перезагрузка сервера / tomcat / postgresql проблему не решает.

Включить режим отладки не получается, поэтому более детальных сведений нет.

```
[
Что делалось для включения режима отладки:
В файле log4j.properties
loglevel.dspace=DEBUG
loglevel.other=DEBUG
Перезагрузка tomcat.
В файл dspace.log.[date] ничего не выводится.
]
```

Буду благодарен за идеи / предположения / предложения.